# Selecting multiple classes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I’ve had a good look and can’t seem to find out how to select all elements matching certain classes in one jQuery selector statement such as this:

```
$('.myClass', '.myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass');
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? The only other option is to do

```
$('.myClass').removeClass('theclass');
$('.myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass');
```

But I’m doing this with quite a few classes, so it requires much code.

Answer (score 409, accepted):

This should work:

`$('.myClass, .myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass');`

You must add the multiple selectors all in the first argument to $(), otherwise you are giving jQuery a context in which to search, which is not what you want.

It's the same as you would do in CSS.

Comment: What if I want to match it only when each of the element have all the specified classes?

Comment: Al right, I got this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/1041344/148271. basically I will have to join all the selector for intersection. Like `$(".myClass.myOtherClass")`

Comment: More on CSS grouping: [W3C "Grouping"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping).

Comment: @wal: That comma is necessary also in CSS when pointing to both classes. Without the comma it'd reference to `.myOtherClass` that is somewhere inside `.myClass`.

Comment: this answer doesn't answer the question, this way you're making an OR!!!!  not AND!!

Comment: Note: this will return all element that have either class.  If you want only elements that have both classes then use  $('.myClass.myOtherClass')

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried this?

```
$('.myClass, .myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass');
```

Answer (score 26):

I use `$('.myClass.myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass');`

Comment: This is if an HTML element has multiple classes, and you want to remove the class for the element only with _all_ of those classes.  Other examples will remove the class from any element with any of the classes that are comma-separated.  Your example would only work if my HTML element had _both_, such as `<div class="myClass myOtherClass theclass">`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Due to this Code ): Syntax problem.    
$('.myClass', '.myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass');
```

According to jQuery documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

When can select multiple classes in this way:

```
jQuery(“selector1, selector2, selectorN”) // double Commas. // IS valid.
jQuery('selector1, selector2, selectorN') // single Commas. // Is valid.
```

by enclosing all the selectors in a single '...' ' or double commas, "..."

So in your case the correct way to call multiple classes is:

```
$('.myClass', '.myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass'); // your Code // Invalid.
$('.myClass , .myOtherClass').removeClass('theclass');  // Correct Code // Is valid.
```