# How can I select an element with multiple classes in jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, htmlelements

I want to select all the elements that have the two classes `a` and `b`.

```
<element class="a b">
```

So, only the elements that have *both* classes.

When I use `$(".a, .b")` it gives me the union, but I want the intersection.

Comment: @KolobCanyon union and intersection are basic set theory concepts. So for instance a union would be all French speakers (includes both men and women), whereas an intersection would be all women who speak French (excludes everyone who does not speak French, and excludes all people who are not women). Unions and intersections can be made with any number of characteristics defining each set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)

Comment: Check these references :[https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors), [https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/](https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/)

Answer (score 2869, accepted):

If you want to match only elements with **both** classes (an intersection, like a logical AND), just write the selectors together **without spaces** in between:

```
$('.a.b')
```

The order is not relevant, so you can also swap the classes:

```
$('.b.a')
```

So to match a `div` element that has an ID of `a` with classes `b` and `c`, you would write:

```
$('div#a.b.c')
```

(In practice, you most likely don't need to get that specific, and an ID or class selector by itself is usually enough: `$('#a')`.)

Comment: @Flater: It was just for the sake of example. But it might be useful if the classes `b` and `c` are dynamically added, and you only want to select the element if it has those classes.

Comment: @Shimmy: Yes. A space between two selectors means you're searching for descendants; i.e. `.a .b` searches for elements with class `b` that are descendants of an element with class `a`. So something like `div a` will only return `a` elements that are *inside* a `div` element.

Comment: What about the "or" case if I want to find elements with .a or .b?

Comment: Check these references :[https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors), [https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/](https://web.dev/learn/css/selectors/)

Answer (score 184):

You can do this using the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
$(".a").filter(".b")
```

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the accepted one?

Comment: @Rice: This one will be a little bit slower, because it will build a list of objects with class "a" first, then remove all but those that have class "b", whereas mine does this in one step. But otherwise, no difference.

Answer (score 139):

For the case

```
<element class="a">
  <element class="b c">
  </element>
</element>
```

You would need to put a space in between `.a` and `.b.c`

```
$('.a .b.c')
```

Answer (score 74):

The problem you're having, is that you are using a `Group Selector`, whereas you should be using a `Multiples selector`! To be more specific, you're using `$('.a, .b')` whereas you should be using `$('.a.b')`.

For more information, see the overview of the different ways to combine selectors herebelow!

---

### Group Selector : ","

Select all `<h1>` elements AND all `<p>` elements AND all `<a>` elements :

```
$('h1, p, a')
```

### Multiples selector : "" (no character)

Select all `<input>` elements of `type` `text`, with classes `code` and `red` :

```
$('input[type="text"].code.red')
```

### Descendant Selector : " " (space)

Select all `<i>` elements inside `<p>` elements:

```
$('p i')
```

### Child Selector : ">"

Select all `<ul>` elements that are immediate children of a `<li>` element:

```
$('li > ul')
```

### Adjacent Sibling Selector : "+"

Select all `<a>` elements that are placed immediately after `<h2>` elements:

```
$('h2 + a')
```

### General Sibling Selector : "~"

Select all `<span>` elements that are siblings of `<div>` elements:

```
$('div ~ span')
```

Answer (score 42):

```js
$('.a .b , .a .c').css('border', '2px solid yellow');
//selects b and c
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">a
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 27):

Just mention another case with element:

E.g. `<div id="title1" class="A B C">`

Just type: `$("div#title1.A.B.C")`

Answer (score 26):

Vanilla JavaScript solution:-

`document.querySelectorAll('.a.b')`

Answer (score 22):

For better performance you can use

```
$('div.a.b')
```

This will look only through the div elements instead of stepping through all the html elements that you have on your page.

Answer (score 17):

your code `$(".a, .b")` will work for below multiple elements (at a same time)

```
<element class="a">
<element class="b">
```

if you want to select element having a and b both class like `<element class="a b">` than use js without comma

```
$('.a.b')
```

Answer (score 10):

Group Selector

```
body {font-size: 12px; }
body {font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
th {font-size: 12px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
td {font-size: 12px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

Becomes this:

```
body, th, td {font-size: 12px; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

So in your case you have tried the group selector whereas its an intersection

```
$(".a, .b")
```

instead use this

```
$(".a.b")
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need `jQuery` for this

In `Vanilla` you can do :

```
document.querySelectorAll('.a.b')
```

Answer (score 4):

Below example will give you idea about to select at a time multiple nested class selectors and direct class selectors in one line

```js
//Here is Explaination of Selectors  
//.a .b .c  = selects nested child c which is inside of div a and b
//.a .d     = selects nested child d which is inside of div a 
//.f        = selects direct element ie div f which is outside of div a and b
$('.a .b .c , .a .d, .f').css('background-color', 'grey');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a">a
  <div class="b">b
       <div class="c">c</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
<div class="e">e</div>
<div class="f">f</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getElementsByClassName()` method for what you want.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("a b c");
elems[0].style.color = "green";
console.log(elems[0]);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">a</li>
  <li class="a b">a, b</li>
  <li class="a b c">a, b, c</li>
</ul>
```

This is the fastest solution also. you can see a benchmark about that [here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/12954).

Answer (score 2):

var elem = document.querySelector(".a.b");