# jQuery select an element by multiple css classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

jQuery [Class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) works well if you have a single class assigned to an element. What if I assign two classes to an element(Ex:  `<div class="one two">`), how can I find that element if I know these two classes?

Comment: Exact dupe: [Jquery multiple class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

Comment: lol.... the OP would like to accept your answer.. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

Answer (score 6):

`$("div.one.two")`

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.one.two');
```

[more on multiple selectors if you just did a search on SO first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)