# I am looking to add a new class to a DIV that already has 2 Classes

Tags: jquery

Hello I have a Div with two classes

```
<div class="box_box my_pages">some text</div>
```

I need to add another class to this div say - myaccordion

The result should be some thing like this :

```
<div class="box_box my_pages myaccordion">some text</div>
```

How do I do that ? I want to add class only when both the classes box_box my_pages exist for a DIV not just a div with the class "box_box" or "my_pages"

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you review the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com). Additionally, it's important that you show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Why don't you Google for the same..? You would have got answer without typing this

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery select an element by multiple css classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950814/jquery-select-an-element-by-multiple-css-classes)

Comment: @FelixKling Exact duplicate :-)

Comment: @Exception: Well, it misses the "add class" part but I'm friendly and link to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/.

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
$('div.box_box.my_pages').addClass('myaccordion');
```