# jquery- store id of clicked link in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be basic, but for some reason its not working for me. I just want to store the id when a link that has a certain class is clicked in a variable so as an example:

```
<a href="#" id="this_id_here" class="only_this_class">Some link</a>
```

I would want jquery to get the id of the link above and store it in a variable. I have tried $this.attr("id") and $this.id, but non of this worked.

This is what I have for the jquery:

```
  $(".only_this_class").click(function() {

      var clickedId= $(this).attr("id");
      alert(clickedId);
   });
```

I just get "undefined" every time.

Comment: sorry about that. That was not a problem just a typo that I did twice when asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the space between `this` and `_class` in `class="only_this _class"` and it is working for me.

[Try this here](http://jsfiddle.net/kuQxb/)

Please have a look at [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

If you have two classes in your HTML then the syntax is different:

```
$('.classA.classB')
```

Have a look at [How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

Comment: ok it actually did work. The problem was that for some reason I ran this at the end of the function before so I guess the id was changed at some point, but when I put this at the beginning I was able to store the id. and thanks for the link to jsfiddle, that sites really useful!

Answer (score 3):

NAVEED is right, if you remove the space it works, because if there is a space HTML will put two classes on the element: only_this and _class.

If you *are* in fact looking for two different classes, you should replace the space with a dot to make it work properly, as in `$(".only_this._class")`

Comment: I only need 1 class but thanks for the extra info. I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".only_this _class")` this selector will look for `_class` tag in `.only_this` element. May you are looking for `$(".only_this")` which will select element which has this class. Try this.

```
   $(".only_this").click(function() {

      var clickedId= $(this).attr("id");
      alert(clickedId);
   });
```