# Assigning more than one class for one event

Tags: jquery, class, events

I have an click event that I want to assign to more than class. The reason for this is that I'm using this event on different places in my application, and the buttons you click have different styling in the different places.

What I want is something like $('.tag' '.tag2'), which of course don't work.

```
    $('.tag').click(function (){
        if ($(this).hasClass('clickedTag')){
            // code here
        }

        else {
             // and here
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fe8ws/ should help, have a nice one! cheerios!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

### Approach #1

```
function doSomething(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('clickedTag')){
        // code here
    }
    else {
         // and here
    }
}

$('.tag1').click(doSomething);
$('.tag2').click(doSomething);

// or, simplifying further
$(".tag1, .tag2").click(doSomething);
```

### Approach #2

This will also work:

```
​$(".tag1, .tag2").click(function(){
   alert("clicked");    
});​
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Afg5s/1/)

I prefer a separate function (approach #1) if there is a chance that logic will be reused.

See also [How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector) for handling multiple classes on the same item.

Comment: In the first example you don't need `$('.tag2').click(doSomething);` cause it's obvious that there's a COMMON class `.tag` for both/or/more elements but just specific ones `clickedTag` http://jsbin.com/ukiguf/2/edit

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - the OP says "I have an click event that I want to assign to more than class." I'm showing a way to do that. It's not clear to me whether or not there is a common class assigned to all the elements in question. If that's the case, the approach would still work.

Comment: Exactly, the more than one are: `.tag` and `.clickedTag` ;) All right. +1 from me (P.S: OP need votes more that we do. [you ever needed to Bounty a Question?] )

Comment: Second approach is what I was looking for Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can select multiple classes at once with jQuery like this:

```
$('.tag, .tag2').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('tag')) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

Giving a 2nd parameter to the $() function, scopes the selector so `$('.tag', '.tag2')` looks for `tag` within elements with the class `tag2`.

Answer (score 7):

```
    $('.tag1, .tag2').on('click', function() {

      if ($(this).hasClass('clickedTag')){
         // code here
      } else {
         // and here
      }

   });
```

or

```
function dothing() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('clickedTag')){
        // code here
    } else {
        // and here
   }
}

$('.tag1, .tag2').on('click', dothing);
```

or

```
 $('[class^=tag]').on('click', dothing);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's like this:

```
$('.tag.clickedTag').click(function (){ 
 // this will catch with two classes
}

$('.tag.clickedTag.otherclass').click(function (){ 
 // this will catch with three classes
}

$('.tag:not(.clickedTag)').click(function (){ 
 // this will catch tag without clickedTag
}
```

Comment: Combinatorial click functions, just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @Systembolaget you're nick name just made me go 5 years to the past :P

Comment: My pleasure :) The future is not what it used to be!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
 function doSomething() {
     if ($(this).hasClass('clickedTag')){
         // code here
     } else {
         // and here
     }
 }

 $('.tag1, .tag2').click(doSomething);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('[class*="tag"]').live('click', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('clickedTag')){
         // code here
      } else {
         // and here
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
​$(".tag1, .tag2").click(function(){
   alert("clicked");    
});​
```

This works:

```
​$(".tag1").add(".tag2").click(function(){
   alert("clicked");    
});​
```

Comment: No, `$(".tag1, .tag2").click(function() {/*...*/})` is **not** wrong.