# It's repetition of code and wish to minimize jquery

Tags: jquery

I have written jquery but there is repetition of code lines. I wish to minimize these lines of code. I haven't an idea how to do it? Can any one help me would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="publish-content">
        <div class="content-title">
            <h5>Publised content</h5>
            <span><img src="images/accordion-arrow.png" alt="down arrow"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><hr>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="upcoming-content">
        <div class="content-title">
            <h5>Upcoming content</h5>
            <span><img src="images/accordion-arrow.png" alt=" down arrow"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--content section ends---------->
```

Please note: I have removed here html of future content.

jquery

```
$('.publish-content').click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        // odd clicks
        $(this).children('.content').slideUp();
        $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
    } else {
        // even clicks
        $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
        $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(90deg)'});
        $('.upcoming-content').children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.upcoming-content').children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
        $('.future-content').children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.future-content').children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
$('.upcoming-content').click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        // odd clicks
        $(this).children('.content').slideUp();
        $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
    } else {
        // even clicks
        $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
        $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(90deg)'});
        $('.publish-content').children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.publish-content').children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
        $('.future-content').children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.future-content').children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Please note: I have removed here jquery of future content.
That's it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning more than one class for one event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511897/assigning-more-than-one-class-for-one-event)

Comment: It would be easy for the community to help if you explain what are you actually trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the function together

If the code is same in both click events:

`$('.publish-content, .upcoming-content').click(function() {...});`

If parts of code are same, go for functions:
For eg:

```
function xyz(){
    $(this).children('.content').slideUp();
    $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
}
```

And then use `xyz();` wherever you want to execute.

```
$('.publish-content').click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        // odd clicks
        xyz();
    } else {
        // even clicks
        $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
        $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(90deg)'});
        $('.upcoming-content').children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.upcoming-content').children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
        $('.future-content').children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.future-content').children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's great. I just used $('.publish-content, .upcoming-content').click(function() {...}); this. and removed upcoming-content and future-content code line from even clicks. It works well individually. But suppose publish-content is clicked and slide down, and on next second click on upcoming-content, publish-content should slide up and upcoming-content slide down. That's not happening here. Can you help me to solve this. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Like I told you in the second half of my answer, create small modules of the code to reuse it wherever you want. So I believe most of the line in both click events are same, cut all the lines to a function and call the function xyz() there with additional functionality what so ever.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I tried but something goes wrong. Can you update your code exactly.

Comment: I have already gave an example in the later part of my answer, I don't understand exactly what more you want

Comment: Please Ignore it and thanks for your suggestions. I found solution and used jquery from here-. https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/Kwbpyj

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma to bind click event handler for multiple elements. user `attr('class')` to get the class name and use it in your script. this way you can generalize the script and minimize your code

```
$('.publish-content, .upcoming-content').click(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        // odd clicks
        $(this).children('.content').slideUp();
        $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
    } else {
        // even clicks
        $(this).children('.content').slideDown();
        $(this).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(90deg)'});
        $('.' + className).children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.' + className).children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
        $('.future-content').children('.content').slideUp();
        $('.future-content').children('div:first').children('span').css({'transform' : 'rotate(0deg)'});
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```