# How can I shorten this code that closes the navigation when a nav-link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This works fine, the first part makes my navigation open/close when the Hamburger is clicked, and the second part of the code makes the navigation close when a nav-link is clicked. All sounds great, and there seems no issue with this... however as a complete beginner to JavaScript, I was just wondering if you can do this without calling document.ready twice?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-button').click(function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
    });
});


 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.nav-link').click(function(){
     $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
   });
 });
```

my html;

```
<a class="nav-button ml-auto">
<span id="nav-icon3"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></span></a>
<div class="fixed-top main-menu">
   <div class="flex-center p-5">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
         <li class="pb-3">
            <span class="nav-text">Where to next?</span>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item delay-1"><a class="nav-link" href="#when">When & Where</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item delay-2"><a class="nav-link" href="#info">About Us</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item delay-3"><a class="nav-link" href="#timetable">Timetable</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item delay-4"><a class="nav-link" href="#photogallery">Photo
            Gallery</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just put both functions inside one `$(document).ready( ... )`

Comment: I think you have to add "jquery" tag in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only can you just put both event handlers in one `document.ready()`, but since they both do the same thing, you don't have to repeat that code either. You can just supply a comma separated second selector that will allow for those elements to be affected as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-button, .nav-link').click(function(){
      $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
    });
});
```

And, you can shorten this even further because when you pass a function to the JQuery object, it is implied that this function should run at [`document.ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function(){
    $('.nav-button, .nav-link').click(function(){
      $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this method is so simple and easier. This method better than my answer.

Comment: I've tried this myself, and also tried copying your code, and it isn't working, the nav doesn't open at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think above code something wrong. I think $('.nav-button, .nav-link')... is correct code.

Comment: @Joshua I had a small typo in my answer, try it again with the updated answer.

Comment: Great, the second solution is working perfectly, however I can't figure out why the top one isn't working with my code? Thanks for the explanation also, very useful as a beginner.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Perfect, they both work, the first solution I did try myself, perhaps I made a typo also, I am very new, this is perfectly explained, and I learnt something new regarding the document.ready. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is fine. But need some fix. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.nav-button').click(function () {
     $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
  });

  $('.nav-link').click(function () {
     $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select and bind multiple classes using one selector. (both blocks are doing the same thing)

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.nav-button, .nav-link').click(function(){
         $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
       });
     });
```

Comment: How is this any different than the answer I posted 5 minutes earlier?

Comment: @ScottMarcus You have to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511897/assigning-more-than-one-class-for-one-event. It will be useful to you.

Comment: @MinwooKim Why? What is it that you think I need to see?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Because asked what the difference was. But I may have misunderstood your question intent because I'm not good at English.

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is the same as your answer, saw your post 5 minutes late. Busy figuring out how to make code different from the text. New to the community. :)