# Calling a div with two classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have a div with two classes:

```
<div class="content pager" style="width: 1156px; float: left; list-style: none outside none;"></div>
```

I want to change the element style with jQuery:

```
$(".content pager").width(0);  //Change the element style width
```

but it doesn't work.  What is wrong in it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".content.pager").width(0);
```

Check **[jQuery's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)** [**Class Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

`width(0)` will not hide its content. You need to `hide` it. Instead of `width(0)`. So, you can try this:

```
$(".content.pager").hide(0); // Will hide the div and free its space.
$(".content.pager").css('visibility', 'hidden'); // Will hide the div and take space belongs to it.
```

Comment: @Rorshak You should use it like `$(".content.pager").width(0);` <-- Note the missing `0`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be jQuery's [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. Basically you search for one class then filter the selection by another.  For your particular needs $(".class1.class2") should be sufficient though.  .filter example:

```
<div class="foo bar">div1</div>
<div class="foo">div2</div>
<div class="bar">div3</div>
​
$(".foo").filter(".bar").css('background-color', 'red');​
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPBZ3/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".content").filter(".pager").width(0);
```

But [thecodeparadox's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742737/calling-a-div-with-two-classes-in-jquery/10742745#10742745) should work too.