# "Better" floating in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm experimenting with CSS and the float property. I have this "website", with a lot of divs aligned to 80px grid and `float: left`:

[image: Simple CSS floating]

Is there a way in CSS to make it looking like this - so the elements can use empty space above them?

[image: More compact - uses empty space above the elements]

Without JavaScript, if it's possible.

Thanks, Martin.

Comment: +1 for the excellent image mock-ups

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11940430/963514

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For tiling dynamic content both horizontally and vertically, the CSS options are:

- `float:left`, as you've already seen, only offers limited horizontal tiling.
- `display:inline-block` gives a different result than `float:left`, but with no tiling.
- [CSS multi-column layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) isn't fully defined yet. It supports vertical flow into implicit columns, but probably not in a way that qualifies as tiling.
- [flexible box layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) isn't well supported yet. It supports a type of horizontal or vertical flow that might not qualify as tiling, though it feels like a step in the right direction.

In short, even the CSS standards that aren't fully defined yet don't seem to support this; so it may be a long ways off. The simplest fallback option is to use a jQuery plug-in.

Besides [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) (as @Billy Moat suggested), another couple jQuery plug-ins are [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and [Tiles Gallery](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/2281417). Masonry seems to be mentioned the most often.

Answer (score 9):

No, this can't be done in CSS. Best way is to use a javascript item called masonry I'm afraid.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1):

lets say that the number of `px` to go up to fill the space of 1 block is `50px`. `margin-top: -50px;`

It's not magic, it's only a bit manual to do that for each ones. If your content is dynamic, this could not work, or need js to calculate if we need to go up or not, on multiple rows and everything.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done, but as CHE says, if your content is dynamic, this will go wrong in the worst possible ways.

But if it is a static site, this can be done, for sure.

To solve this, think in blocks & group and align them, inside each block re-align all blocks.