# What is the selector to extract first image within infobox of a Wikipedia page using Wikipedia API

Tags: jquery, mediawiki-api

I wish to extract the the first image within infobox - the table with the class name infobox that is on most Wikipedia pages, using Wikipedia/Mediawiki API

Here's what I've tried so far -

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=mobileview&format=json&page=mumbai&redirect=no&sections=0&prop=text&sectionprop=toclevel%7Clevel%7Cline%7Cnumber%7Cindex%7Cfromtitle%7Canchor&callback=?", function(json) { 
var wikitext = json.mobileview.sections[0].text;
var img = $(wikitext).find('img:first').attr("src");

/*
//how can i make this work?

//selector for element with multiple classes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector
  var infoboximg = $(wikitext).find('table.infobox.geography.vcard img:first').attr("src");
console.log(infoboximg);  
*/

$('#pic').append('<img src="http://' + img + '" />');

}
);
```

You can try the snippet here - http://jsbin.com/erudum/5/

How can I fix the code to grab the first image within the table having the name infobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to get the src only?  why not just append the img like this

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=mobileview&format=json&page=mumbai&redirect=no&sections=0&prop=text&sectionprop=toclevel%7Clevel%7Cline%7Cnumber%7Cindex%7Cfromtitle%7Canchor&callback=?", function(json) { 
        var wikitext = json.mobileview.sections[0].text;
        var img = $(wikitext).find('img:first');
        $('#pic').append(img);
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/Kr46e/

**EDIT**

After looking at the return text.. it is actually an array of ELEMENTS that's returned.. The table is the 5th element so you can get it use the .eq() method in jQuery

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=mobileview&format=json&page=mumbai&redirect=no&sections=0&prop=text&sectionprop=toclevel%7Clevel%7Cline%7Cnumber%7Cindex%7Cfromtitle%7Canchor&callback=?", function(json) { 
        var wikitext = json.mobileview.sections[0].text;
        var img = $(wikitext).eq(4).find('img:first').attr('src');
        $('#pic').append('<img src="' + img + '"/>');
    }
);
```

You can do a console.log to see what I mean

```
console.log($(wikitext));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/Jp7rn/

**EDIT AGAIN**

I figured out why it's coming back as an array.  The quotes in the text is throwing it off.  What I would do is append the whole thing.. maybe to a hidden field or something.. then traverse it and get the img text. then remove the whole thing again.  Here's an example

```
$.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=mobileview&format=json&page=mumbai&redirect=no&sections=0&prop=text&sectionprop=toclevel%7Clevel%7Cline%7Cnumber%7Cindex%7Cfromtitle%7Canchor&callback=?", function(json) { 
    var wikitext = json.mobileview.sections[0].text;
    $('#pic').hide().append(wikitext); // hide the div then append whole string
    var img = $('#pic').find('.infobox img:first').attr('src');// find the src
    $('#pic').show().html('<img src="' + img + '"/>'); // show and append
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jp7rn/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good alternative. Why it can't be accessed through the table class selector stumps me though.

Comment: If I can use the infobox class in the selector, I'm assured that there will be a meaningful image on most Wikipedia pages. I guess, the presence & exact position of the other elements is not guaranteed for all/most Wikipedia pages(will the table always be the 5th element?)

Comment: @mvark Actually, no it won't be.  I just edited my answer.  It seems the quotes in the text is probably culprit.  What you can do is append the whole thing.. traverse it.. get what you want.. remove it again

Comment: Better use the [PageImages API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages#API) now.