# Add multiple variables on javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, variables

How can I pass multiple variables on a jquery function? Like so:

```
$(".link1",".link2").click(function(event){

}
```

Also tried:

```
$(".link1"),$(".link2").click(function(event){

}
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1041344/920200

Comment: Are you wanting to bind the same function to the click event of anything that has a class of either 'link1' and/or 'link2'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple selectors need only be separated by a comma in your selector string.

```
$(".link1, .link2").click(function(event){

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
$(".link1, .link2").click(function(event){
```

or

```
$(".link1").add(".link2").click(function(event){
```

The comma separator is defined here : [Multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

use `.on`, and pass the extra events as an argument to that method:

```
$('.link1, link2').on('click',{some:'argument'},function(e)
{
    console.log(e.data);//<-- object literal {some:'arguments'}
});
```

[Read all about it here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)