# jQuery selector with many classes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a class="control selected" id="control1" rel="1" href="#"></a>
<a class="control" id="control2" rel="2" href="#"></a>
<a class="control" id="control3" rel="3" href="#"></a>
```

I have a jQuery Slider that have thumbnails in a tags like this:

To make it dynamic, I try to select each

```
$('#control1.control').css("background-color", "red");
$('#control1.control.selected').css("background-color", "green");
```

The first selector works, but not the second.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9mzfW/ -- seems like it works; there must be something else going on

Comment: In this particular case, it would probably be better to add the CSS styles to your stylesheet and not use any jQuery at all.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I have to use jQuery while what I have to insert are dynamic images in css. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both selectors work. See I highlighted the first with red and the second with green colors:

```
<a class="control" id="control1" rel="1" href="#">1</a>
<a class="control selected" id="control2" rel="2" href="#">2</a>
<a class="control" id="control3" rel="3" href="#">3</a>
<script>
$('#control1.control').css("background-color", "red");
$('#control2.control.selected').css("background-color", "green");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
$('#control1.control.selected').css("background-color", "green");
```

Here is explanation on other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector), but yes, use single id in a query:

```
$('#control1')
```

Comment: `$('.selected')` --> do you mean `$('#control1')`?