# FadeIn div not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a code in `_layout.cshtml`.

```
@if (TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @TempData["SuccessMessage"];
    </div>
}
```

And in javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(".alert alert-success").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

But the div is not fading out. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your jQuery selector is wrong. Try `$(".alert.alert-success")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery Docs - Class Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) has an example that is quite relevant (Finds the element with both "myclass" and "otherclass" classes.)

Try changing:

```
$(function () {
  $(".alert alert-success").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

To:

```
$(function () {
  $(".alert.alert-success").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

or you could try [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(".alert").filter(".alert-success")
```

However, this method will be slightly slower since you are first compiling a set of all match `.alert` elements and then filtering those to compile a second set or those containing `.alert-success`.

Find more info in a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

Answer (score 1):

this are two classes  `alter` and `alert-success` so you need to do

```
$(".alert.alert-success").fadeOut("slow");
```

OR

```
$(".alert-success").fadeOut("slow");
```

OR

```
$(".alert").fadeOut("slow");
```