# is there a way to get the intersect of selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of 4 elements.  each one belongs to 2 of 4 classes, so each class combination is unique.  I want to find a way, with jQuery, to select only one of the elements, based on it's unique class combination.  Is this possible?

I'm expecting something like

```
$(".class1 & .class2")
```

is this reasonable?

jsFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7UfYH/

Comment: *"...based on it's unique class combination."* What does that mean? It seems different from the example you gave, which isn't about a unique class combination, but (seemingly) just about an element having both of those classes...

Comment: I mean that for my example, every element has a unique combination of classes.  in my jsfiddle, for instance, only one div has both the "jon" and "stark" classes.

Comment: Looks like it is.  I didn't think to search for "multiple" though.  I'll try to think of more synonyms next time, and maybe my tiny bit of reputation won't get wiped out again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do

```
$(".class1.class2")
```

But I actally don't get what your fiddle has to do do with that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just like you would in CSS.

Comment: In the fiddle, I'm trying to achieve turning the div with the "jon" and "stark" classes black.

Your suggestion worked perfectly though. thanks.

Comment: @Simon: Answers can't be marked "accepted" within the first 15 minutes of the question being asked.

Comment: @Simon: I wanted to, I was just waiting for the timer to expire.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

For a terrible solution that still works...

```
$('.class1').filter('.class2');
```

or

```
$('.class2').filter('.class1');
```

Note, the $('.class1.class2') selector is unquestionably the fastest solution. But if any people who see this answer who never knew what `filter()` was, now they have a decent grasp, and may be able to expand on that logic.

Consider if someone asks "How do I select an element with ID whatever in jQuery?" Obviously, the fastest/most obvious answer is `$('#id')`. But answers such as `$('*[id="' + id + '"]')` provide alternative insight which may or may not be more useful than the obvious answer itself.

Comment: How was this down-voted? It's a valid answer, and I even specify that it's terrible, only because the obvious solution is just so obvious.

Comment: A valid answer would also be: `var $elem = $('.class1'); $elem = ($elem.hasClass('class2')) ? $elem : $();`. But nobody would do that. And you have to admit that everyone is trying to find the best solution... and yours isn't. Why would you use that?

Comment: @Simon Trying to find the best solution?? A simple search would reveal TONS of posts on how to select two classes with jQuery, this question is worthless and thus deserves a worthless answer.

Comment: Well I dont't think that that guy knew about what he actually wanted to look for, as you can see in his question title. But if you want to give a worthless answer then don't be surprised when you get downvoted. Your answer might be right, but quality gets voted as well.

Comment: Ironic since in the in the main thread for this topic, this identical answer got 42 votes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector

Comment: I'll remove my downvote I'm not sure where this dicussion will go. In my opinion, it should be an appeal to find the best/fastest solution and not just any solution. But if you have other thoughts about that... keep going.

Comment: @BradM for what it's worth, I had an extremely convoluted situation where, for reasons too complicated to type out, the better solution was not applicable. Yours, on the other hand, worked, and saved me a lot of headache.