# How to add attribute 'id' to a class in JavaScript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with id and a class. I am using a plugin to fix the first two column and the header in order to meet my requirements. My table is defined by the tag:

```
<table class="fancyTable" id="myTable03" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

I wanted to add another features to this table. After inspecting the DOM through firebug, I found out that the table is broken up into two parts by the plugin(I supposed). While one part of the table becomes

```
<table class="fht-table fancyTable" style="margin-top: 0px;">
```

and the other one becomes

```
<table id="myTable03" class="fancyTable fht-table fht-table-init" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 926px; margin-top: -40px;">
```

I want to add attribute id to the table containing the class "fht-table fancyTable". How can i do that? I'm using Jquery/javascript.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. The jQuery documentation has a section about DOM manipulation, you might want to have a look at it first: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/general-attributes/. If you don't know how to select the correct element have a look at [jQuery multiple class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1041344/218196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From** the second one you have already an id `myTable03`

If you want to add `attribute id` to the table containing the class `fht-table fancyTable`

Then try this,

```
$(".fht-table.fancyTable:not('#myTable03')").attr('id','myTable04');
```

Read [How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

Comment: you definitely show me the hint. $(".fht-table.fancyTable").attr("id", "myTable");
   $(".fht-table.fancyTable.fht-table-init").attr("id", "myTable03"); i got my answers now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need something like this:

```
$('.fht-table.fancyTable').not('#myTable03').prop('id', 'yourId');
```

or

```
$('.fht-table.fancyTable').not('.fht-table-init').prop('id', 'yourId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute ID can be added as normal attribution for properties. But reference to that element should not be get by Id.

You can use:

```
$("div").attr("id", "div1");
```

Note: Two element must not have same id.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

or

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('fancyTable');


for(var i = 0; i<divs.length;i++) {
    divs[i].setAttribute("id","div"+i);
}
```