# Filter based on combination of multiple select and single select elements

Tags: jquery, filtering, selection

I want to filter (show/hide) elements by class. I want to have lets say 5 filters working together.

```
<select id='filter4'>...</select>
<select id='filter5'>...</select>
<select id='filter6'>...</select>
<select id='filter7'>...</select>
```

and

```
<select id='filter6' multiple>...</select>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("select").on("change", function () {
        var filterVal = $("select#filter4").val();
        var filterVal2 = $("select#filter5").val();
        var filterVal3 = $("select#filter6").val();
        var filterVal4 = $("select#filter7").val();
        var filterVal5 = $("select#filter8").val();
        var filterSelector = "";
        var filter2Selector = "";
        var filter3Selector = "";
        var filter4Selector = "";
        var filter5Selector = "";

        if (filterVal == "all" && filterVal2 == "all" && filterVal3 == "all" && filterVal4 == "all" && filterVal5 === null) {
            //show all items 
            $(".item").fadeIn("fast");
        } else {
            if (filterVal != "all") {
                filterSelector = "." + filterVal;
            }

            if (filterVal2 != "all") {
                filter2Selector = "." + filterVal2;
            }

            if (filterVal3 != "all") {
                filter3Selector = "." + filterVal3;
            }

            if (filterVal4 != "all") {
                filter4Selector = "." + filterVal4;
            }

            if (filterVal5 !== null) {
                filter5Selector = "." + filterVal5;
            }

            $(".item").hide();
            $(filterSelector + filter2Selector + filter3Selector + filter4Selector + filter5Selector).fadeIn("fast");
        }

    });
});
```

See [everything in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahish/dum7n/7/) !

The first four single filters work with any problem. The fifth multi-select element does not work (filter) properly when more than one option is selected.

**EDIT**: It was needed to replace commas with dots (multiple css selectors) with help of g modifier (/ /g) which is global match:

```
$(filter4Selector + filter5Selector.replace(/,/g, ".")).fadeIn("fast");
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/mahish/dum7n/ .

Answer below offers different code which works as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned up your code and fixed the multiple queries. Note that:

`.class1.class2.class3` means `class1 && class2 && class 3`

`.class1, .class2, .class3` means `class1 || class2 || class 3`

That was cause of earlier confusion in the comments.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var values = [7, 8];

    $("select").on("change", function () {

        var showAll = true,
            show = [],
            joined;

        $.each(values, function (index, id) {
            var $el = $('#filter' + id),
                multi = $el.attr('multiple'),
                val = $el.val();

            if (multi) {
                if (val !== null) {
                    showAll = false;
                    $.each(val, function (i, v) {
                        show.push( v );
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if (val != 'all') {
                    showAll = false;
                    show.push( val );
                }
            }


        });

        console.log(showAll);
        console.log(show);

        if (showAll) {
            //show all items 
            $(".item").fadeIn("fast");
        } else {

            joined = '.' + show.join('.');

            console.log( joined );

            $(".item").hide();
            $( joined ).fadeIn("fast");
        }

    });

    $.each(values, function (index, id) {
        $('#filter' + id).chosen();
    });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9SZkr/1/

Comment: Wow, thats pretty neat. Nice learning curve for me.. Although, multiple options still not working. I should change the language sry.

Comment: I wasn't adding the multiple select values properly

Comment: Actually, the whole filter thing doesnt work at all right now:( Copy html from this fiddle to has letters instead of czech words to see results clearly. http://jsfiddle.net/mahish/Bd8S9/

Comment: Keep your console open and you'll see all the classes that it's supposed to show. Your markup has a lot of em so another challenge for me :)

Comment: You just need the `$.each` in the multi value getting.. 14 has it and so does the other

Comment: Is the `console.log` for the classes of `show` wrong? I see it populating with everything. Are you sure your markup has the matching classes?

Comment: values, labels, classes all are originally PHP generated. Console is right since it shows what you select. The real results are wrong tho. Something must be wrong in between. And even you select an additional `option` from different single dropdown `select` (Didaktické procesy -> Analyzovat i.e.), the results get messed.

Comment: Yeah the ABCD didn't help much I'd need the whole thing to be simple english sentences to know. I just keep seeing gibberish come in and out that doesn't correspond to the labels ya know? I only speak French and English ;)

Comment: :) I know, i ve changed that just for visual ease:) Going to change the whole thing then!

Comment: It looks fine to me... it's supposed to be what you choose in the multi + the one from single dropdown right?

Comment: Or did you want one to override the other?

Comment: Look at this http://gyazo.com/df19a1adeb695523bbaaf2c4e46bb44d , the result simply doesnt match with selected options.

Comment: I want `filter1 && filter2 && filter3`. Now it behaves more like `filter1 || filter2 || filter3` ...

Comment: Ohhhh that's a real simple change!

Comment: Fixed it buddy. Now it uses `&&` logic rather than `||`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. You showed me different perspective on my code. I will keep with my original code tho. THe only thing I need to do was to replace commas with dots.

Comment: Oh. Didnt notice your recent comment. Gimme link, let me check:) This mine working version btw: http://jsfiddle.net/mahish/dum7n/ . The line changed: `$(filter4Selector + filter5Selector.replace(/,/g, ".")).fadeIn("fast");`

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I will edit my original post with mine solution as well.

Comment: Just don't forget to remove the `console`s ;)

Answer (score 0):

Separate the selectors with commas and that should work (google jQuery multiple selectors for more information)

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction. However, I needed to replace commas with dots – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector .