# How to change img url? (with/ class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

Add/remove animate-in/out class it works (http://hostelgoodmo.com/test.gif), and how to change img url?

New slide => Add gif => Start gif animation => (remove old gif) Next slide => Add gif ....

Slide 1:

```
<li class="slide-one animate-in">
<img src="active.gif">
</li>

<li class="slide-two">
<img src="none.png">
</li>

<li class="slide-four">
<img src="none.png">
</li>

</ul>
```

Slide 2:

```
<li class="slide-one animate-out">
<img src="none.png">
</li>

<li class="slide-two animate-in">
<img src="active.gif">
</li>

<li class="slide-four">
<img src="none.png">
</li>

</ul>
```

Slide 3:

```
<ul class="animation-canvas">

<li class="slide-one animate-out">
<img src="none.png">
</li>

<li class="slide-two animate-in">
<img src="none.png">
</li>

<li class="slide-four">
<img src="active.gif">
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple :

```
$('selector_to_img_tag').attr('src','what you want');
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$('.slide-one .placeimg').attr('src','slide_1.gif');
$('.slide-one.animate-out .placeimg').attr('src','none.png');
});

Does not work :(

Comment: @developingidea where is the placeimg class ?

Comment: @developingidea follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1041352/1426743) to use multiple class selector

Answer (score 1):

Change the src attribute of the image using jQuery.

**HTML :**

```
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapersdj.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/cartoon-1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />

<input type="button" value="Change Image" />
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("input").click(function(){
    var newImageUrl = "http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/14000000/Disney-Cartoon-wallpaper-classic-disney-14019904-1024-768.jpg";
    $("img").attr("src", newImageUrl);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/HSKf9/)