# Having two class names in a jquery click function

Tags: jquery, click

I'm using the class btn1 to control the display of some buttons.

I have a click function set up that works fine

```
$('#rotation').on('click', '.btn1'...
```

This calls the same click function for all btn1 buttons.

I'm trying to figure out how to have the same display class, but call different functions for each button eg

```
$('#rotation').on('click', '.btn1 process1'...
```

when this is clicked

```
<div class="btn1 process1">
```

and

```
$('#rotation').on('click', '.btn1 process2'...
```

when this is clicked

```
<div class="btn1 process2">
```

They aren't working. Is it possible to do, or do I need to set up IDs for each button, and set the click functions to listen for the IDs and not class?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I think you can just use the old code then perform some check right in the handler like this `if($(this).hasClass('process1')) ... else ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery multiple class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery selectors follow CSS rules, so if you want to target an element with two classes, don't use a space between the class names, like this:

```
$('#rotation')
    .on('click', '.btn1.process1', fn)
    .on('click', '.btn1.process2', fn);
```

Alternatively you can have a single click handler and use `hasClass` to identify the button clicked:

```
$('#rotation').on('click', '.btn1', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('process1')) {
        // do something
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('process2')) {
        // do something else
    }
})
```