# jQuery select inputs with more than one class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sum, multiple-value

I have a number of `input`s with multiple class:

```
<p><span>Efectivo X: </span><input type="text" class="montox numero caja1" name="mefectx" id="mefectx" maxlength="10" placeholder="0"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="montox numero caja2" name="mefectx" id="mefectx" maxlength="10" placeholder="0"/></p>
        <p><span>Tarjeta de Cr&eacute;dito X: </span><input type="text" class="montox numero caja1" name="mtdcx" id="mtdcx" maxlength="10" placeholder="0"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" class="montox numero caja2" name="mtdcx" id="mtdcx" maxlength="10" placeholder="0"/></p>
```

I want to sum all input with class (`montox caja1`):

```
var montosx = $('[class="montox"][class="caja1"]').sumVal();
        $('#tcajax').val(montosx);
```

But that code doesn't work.

Comment: `$('.motox.caja1')`? What is `sumVal`?

Comment: It looks like you've used something like XPath here, whereas jQuery needs a CSS selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your sumVal function working as expected?  This will get all elements that have both classes:

```
var montosx = $('.montox.caja1').sumVal();
$('#tcajax').val(montosx);
```

Comment: Yea it works and i see the samre result here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector) Thaks for the Help...