# not select first li element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jquery selector ,

```
$($('ul *[data-date="abc"]'))
```

Retrieves following elements from html,

```
<li class="current week" data-wk="39" data-date="abc"></li>
<li class="day" data-date="abc"></li>
..
..
..
.
.
<li class="day" data-date="abc"></li>
```

But I dont want its first element. How to do that ?

What I have tried is ,

```
$($('ul *[data-date="abc"]:not(.current week)'))
```

But it is still returning all the results.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector

Answer (score 1):

`current week` are 2 different classes, so you need to use

```
$('ul *[data-date="abc"]:not(.current.week)')
```

Also there is no need to use 2 sets of `$`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude first element then try this:

```
$('ul *[data-date="abc"]:not(:first)')
```

Or if you want to exclude elements with **class** `current week` then try this :

```
$('ul *[data-date="abc"]:not(.current.week)')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the least selector

```
$("ul li.day[data-date='abc']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul *[data-date="abc"]').find("li:gt(0)")
```

You can try using the gt(0) in the find selector. 0 is the first LI element. The above statement will return all the LI's except the first one.