# Hiding a Div Class using J Query on when page is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a div class field using j query and i am unable to do so. It is a ticket field in a support form. That needs to be hidden at the beginning and reflect when a particular value is selected. I does not work. I have tried it two different ways and it does not work. Below is the HTML Code, HTML Image and the JQuery Code that i have used.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-field string optional request_custom_fields_21158635">
  <label for="request_custom_fields_21158635">iOS Plugin Details</label>
  <input id="request_custom_fields_21158635" type="text" name="request[custom_fields][21158635]">
  <p>Please provide the iOS Plugin version details for your request. Example: iOS GA5.0.38</p>
</div>
```

J Query Code: One Hides only field and label remains visible.

```
var iosPluginId = "21158635";
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(cust_tags == "kony_internal") {
    $('#request_custom_fields_'+iosPluginId).hide();
  }
});
```

JQuery Code: Two Both the label and field are visible.

```
$(".form-field string optional request_custom_fields_21158635").hide();
```

[image: HTML Image]

Comment: What is the value of `cust_tags`? Also you have syntax error *document ready* handler is not closed properly. Also try `$(".form-field.string.optional.request_custom_fields_21158635").hide();`

Comment: its better to provide a unique class name for the div and call the hide().$(".myclass").hide(); also provide myclass class for that div element

Comment: selector you are using is looking for a tagname, not a class

Comment: Hi, The user when he clicks on submit a form, Will take him  to the form page. Under Category option. If the user selects iPhone then this field needs to be displayed. Otherwise it needs to be hidden.

Comment: I think, if condition is not getting satisfied because $('#request_custom_fields_'+iosPluginId).hide(); this is proper code to hide the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code. It will work.

`$('#request_custom_fields_'+iosPluginId).hide();`
change this to below code.

you cannot use # for class. You have to use "." for class and "#" for id.

```
   $('.request_custom_fields_'+iosPluginId).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using multiple selectors, if you can use them together like

```
$(".form-field.string.optional.request_custom_fields_21158635").hide();
```

it will be intersection, it means select element which have all of the classes. Or if you want a union, you can use

```
$(".form-field, .string.optional, .request_custom_fields_21158635").hide();
```

which means select element which have atleast one class

Related question : [How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oLhn5hfn/)