# Remove child class from active div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem to remove only img class from active div :

```
<div class="thumb thumb-selected">

<img class="img-thumb BWFilter BWfade" src="100x100.jpg" alt=""><img crossorigin="anonymous" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" class="img-thumb" src="3-100x100.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

I want to remove (BWFilter BWfade) class, only for this div (.thumb .thumb-selected), I'm trying with this jquery code:

```
$('.thumb .thumb-selected').find('.img-thumb img').removeClass("BWFilter BWfade");
```

Comment: Try this $('div.thumb').find('img').removeClass("BWFilter BWfade");

Comment: Please use below given JS code I hope it will resolve your issue

Comment: Use `'.thumb.thumb-selected'` as the selector (i.e. remove the space) to find elements with both classes.

Comment: Thank you for your request but i need to find only selected div and remove class only for selected div in this case the code remove BWFilter BWfade from all thumb div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the removeClass accepts more then one class to remove:

```
 $('.thumb.thumb-selected > img.img-thumb').removeClass('BWFilter BWfade');
```

The `>` - selector will only match when the `img` is a direct child of your div.

**Reference**

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

[css - child-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Less code for sure. The first selector will only select the `div` element having the `.thumb` AND `.thumb-selected` class name. Then, `.find()` function is to get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements. For this case, will find out the `img tag` and remove the `.BMFilter and .BWfade` class name attached on it.

```
$('div.thumb.thumb-selected').find('img').removeClass("BWFilter BWfade");
```

Comment: Thank you but I want remove only BWFilter and BWfade class when div.thumb is selected with class thumb-selected

Comment: Is it like this?. $('div.thumb.thumb-selected').find('img').removeClass("BWFilter BWfade"); See edited posted.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this jquery line:

```
$('.thumb.thumb-selected').find('img.img-thumb').removeClass("BWFilter BWfade");
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6xk0sz9/)

Removed space from `$('.thumb .thumb-selected')`.

Reference: [How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.thumb-selected').find('.BWFilter').removeClass("BWFilter").removeClass("BWfade");
```

Comment: Thank you, i just try this solution but nothing :( how can I test, if find()reach the .thumb-selected ? thank you!

Comment: you can check in firebug using console.log($('.thumb-selected'));

Answer (score 0):

Please use below given JS code

```
$('.thumb-selected').find('.img-thumb').removeClass("BWFilter").removeClass(' BWfade');
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this solution but  nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
$('div.thumb.thumb-selected').find('img.img-thumb').removeClass("BWFilter BWfade");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.thumb.thumb-selected').find('img.img-thumb').removeClass("BWFilter BWfade");
```