# How to give an element with an id a certain CSS property if it has a class?

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
<div id="login-light" class="bg-green"></div>
```

My CSS:

```css
#login-light {
    background-color: red;
}

.bg-green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

how can I make my element have the background color green when it has the class `.bg-green`? I know that the CSS of an id takes priority over a class. I want to try and do this without JavaScript.

Comment: maybe add an `!important` after the first background-color

Comment: i try to avoid using !important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another `selector` that is more specific:

```
#login-light.bg-green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this was the simple solution I was looking for !

Comment: i tried it before with a space in between , that was why it was not working

Comment: @JimPeeters Yes, a space indicates two separate elements in a parent -> child relationship

Comment: @JimPeeters : For question "How can I select an element with multiple classes?", I wrote an overview of the different ways to combine different selectors. You might find it interesting ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes/34911808#34911808

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [HTMLDog](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/) to read up on specificity, a summary is a the bottom of the page. A id noted in CSS is more specific than a class.

> Calculating Specificity
>
> The actual specificity of a group of nested selectors takes some calculating. Basically, you give every ID selector (“#whatever”) a value of 100, every class selector (“.whatever”) a value of 10 and every HTML selector (“whatever”) a value of 1. Then you add them all up and hey presto, you have the specificity value.
>
> p has a specificity of 1 (1 HTML selector)
> div p has a specificity of 2 (2 HTML selectors, 1+1)
> .tree has a specificity of 10 (1 class selector)
> div p.tree has a specificity of 12 (2 HTML selectors + a class selector, 1+1+10)