# Find element in document using HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I need to be able to select and modify an element in an HTML document. The usual way to find an element using jQuery is by using a selector that selects by attribute, id, class or element type.
However in my case I have the element's  HTML DOM and I want to find the element on my document that matches this DOM.

**Important :**

I know I can use a class selector or ID selector etc.. but sometimes the HTMLs I get don't have a class or an ID or an attribute to select with, So I need to be able to select from the element's HTML.

For example here is the element I need to find :

```
<span class='hello' data='na'>Element</span>
```

I tried to use jQuery's Find() but it does not work, here is the jsfiddle of the trial : https://jsfiddle.net/ndn9jtbj/

Trial :

```
el = jQuery("<span class='hello' data='na'>Element</span>");
jQuery("body").find(el).html("modified element");
```

The following code does not make any change on the element that is present in my HTML and that corresponds to the DOM I have supplied.
Is there any way to get the desired result either using native Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Please try this: `jQuery("body").find(el).html("modified html");`

Comment: So what's wrong with using any relevant selector, e.g: `$('i.fa.fa-camera').html("modified html");`???

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I tried body also but with the same result

Comment: Do you include jquery script ?

Comment: @A.Wolff I can't use the selectors that way because of the way I structure data, I need to be able to select using the full html DOM of the element needed.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes of course

Comment: @FaouziFJTech Do you mean you want something like this: `el = jQuery('<i class="fa fa-camera"></i>').html("modified html").appendTo('body');`? It is really not clear what is your expected behaviour imho. I don't get if it is an element already available in the DOM or an disconnected element you just created

Comment: @A.Wolff nope I don't wanna add that element to the body, that element already exists on the body and I use its HTML string to find it and modify it.

Comment: @FaouziFJTech So i really don't get why you can't use any relevant CSS selector?! You should really improve question with a minimalistic sample replicating your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't want to use a selector, I need to use that data since this is the data I get, sometimes some HTML strings I need to find will not have selectors means no class , no ID etc... so can only use its external HTML to find it. Here's an example of the problem in this JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ndn9jtbj/

Comment: @FaouziFJTech, I've post an answer for you.

Comment: @A.Wolff can you post your answer that involves the filter in a post, that's the only solution that worked, in my case it would be reliable because I save the whole document and that html element, so they will always match with the browser parsing since I save that parsing.

Comment: @FaouziFJTech If you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ndn9jtbj/3/  This is a no go for sure because browser can parse element differently so this isn't a reliable way to filter any element, using outerHTML property (nor inner HTML one btw)  EDIT: ok, cross posting comments ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter it by `outerHTML` property if you are sure how browser had parsed it:

```
var $el = jQuery("body *").filter(function(){
   return this.outerHTML === '<span class="hello" data="na">Element</span>';
});
$el.html("modified element");
```

Comment: That's the only solution that worked, thanks a ton !

Comment: This is both clever and a little bit horrible. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
el = jQuery('<i class="fa fa-camera"></i>');
```

This does **not** say "find the element that looks like `<i class="fa fa-camera"></i>`". It means "create a new `i` element with the two classes `fa` and `fa-camera`. It's [the signature for creating new elements on the fly](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2).

jQuery selectors look like CSS, not like HTML. To find the `i` element with those two classes, you need a selector like `i.fa.fa-camera`.

Furthermore `$("document")` looks for an HTML element called `document`. This does not exist. To select the actual document, you need `$(document)`. You **could** do this:

```
$(document).find('i.fa.fa-camera').html("modified html")
```

or, more simply, you could do this:

```
$('i.fa.fa-camera').html('modified html');
```

You indicate in a comment to your question that you need to find an element based on a string of HTML that you receive. This is, to put it mildly, difficult, because, essentially, HTML ceases to exist once a browser has parsed it. It gets turned into a DOM structure. It can't just be a string search.

The best you can do is something like this:

```
var searchEl = jQuery('<i class="fa fa-camera"></i>');
var tagName = searchEl.prop('tagName');
var classes = [].slice.apply(searchEl.prop('classList'));

$(tagName + "." + classes.join('.')).html('modified html');
```

Note that this will only use the tag name and class names to find the element. If you also want IDs or something else, you'd need to add that along the same lines.

Comment: That's a good solution if we have a guarantee there will be always at least one selector, however it will not work when there are no selectors

Comment: @FaouziFJTech What does "when there are no selectors" look like? Can you give an example?

Comment: yep for example, <span>this is an example</span>

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript getting the elements by something like

```
document.getElementById...
document.getElementsByClassName...
document.getElementsByTagName...
```

Javascript is returning the elements with the Id, Class or Tag Name you chose.

Answer (score 0):

You can get en element with `document.querySelector('.fa-camera')`

with querySelector you can select `IDs` and `Classes`

Comment: I need to use the full html, using a selector is not an option since there might be cases where I won't have any selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can simply refer to it by its class names.

```
$('.fa.fa-camera').html("modified html");
```

Similar to this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041352/409556

Here is a full example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fa.fa-camera').html("modified html");

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa fa-camera"><h1>Some HTML</h1></i>


</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: I need to use the full html, using a selector is not an option since there might be cases where I won't have any selectors.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that you could use is to check attributes (class and id goes here too in some way) that element have, and the build jQuery selector or [DOM querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the element you need. The hardest part would be to find element based on innerHTML property - "Element" text inside it, for this one you'll probably have to grab all similar element and then search through them.

```
<span class='hello' data='na'>Element</span>
jQuery('body').find('span.hello[data=\'na\']').html('modified element')
```

Take notice of 'span' - that's tag selector, '.hello' - class, '[data="na"]' data attribute with name of data.

Jsfiddle [link here](https://jsfiddle.net/ndn9jtbj/4/) that extends your example;