# Submitting form with POST, information about CHECKED checkboxes is Not being posted/submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

In the following SSCCE, I have three tabs titled `Starks`, `Lannisters` and `Targaryens`. Then I have a form containing a few checkboxes and a button labelled `Save`. When this form is submitted, I want the following information to be submitted:

1. The title of the *selected/active* tab
2. The label of the selected/checked checkboxes

For 2, I have added `<input type="checkbox" name="columnHeadersToDisplay" value="STRING-LABEL-OF-THIS-CHECKBOX" />` elements into the form.

For 1, I have written a click handler for the `Save` button in JS, in which I have appended a ***hidden*** `input` field inside the form and given it a value of the string-title-of-the-tab which is active.

**The problem is that when I check a couple of checkboxes, and also activate/open the `Lannisters` tab and press the `Save` button (so the form is submitted) and I print out the contents of `$_POST`, I get:**

**`Array ( [activeTabTitle] => Starks )`**

What I needed and what I was expecting (when I checked the first two checkboxes) was

**`Array ( [activeTabTitle] => Lannisters, [columnHeadersToDisplay] => Array ( [0] => Apes, [1] => Himalayas, [2] => Malaysia ) )`**

**The question is that why am I not getting the title of *the active* tab, and why is any information about the checked checkboxes not being posted/submitted?**

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
<?php 
$columnNames = array('Apes', 'Himalayas', 'Malaysia', 'Asia', 'Britian', 'Austria', 'Norway', 'Greece', 'Thailand', 'Maldives');


if ( isset($_POST) ) {

    print_r($_POST);//check


} else {
    echo 'isset($_POST["columnHeadersToDisplay"]) returns false.';
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="material.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="material.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">

<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs">
    <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
        <a href="#starks-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active" id="starks-tab">Starks</a>
        <a href="#lannisters-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab" id="lannisters-tab">Lannisters</a>
        <a href="#targaryens-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab" id="targaryens-tab">Targaryens</a>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-tabs__panel is-active" id="starks-panel" style="width:1000px; height:100px; background-color:wheat;">
        .
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-tabs__panel" id="lannisters-panel" style="width:1000px; height:100px; background-color:orange;">
        .
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-tabs__panel" id="targaryens-panel" style="width:1000px; height:100px; background-color:green;">
        .
    </div>
</div>

<form method="post" action="" id="chooseColumnsForm" >

<?php 
echo "<button type='button' id='submit-form-button' style='padding:15px;'>Save</button>";

foreach ($columnNames as $index=>$columnName) {
    echo "<div>
        <input type='checkbox' name='columnHeadersToDisplay[]' value='$columnName' />
        <label>$columnName</label>
    </div>";
}


?>

</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***scripts.js:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit-form-button").click(function(event) {
        alert('$("#submit-form-button") clicked');//check
        //alert(  $("#chooseColumnsForm").html()  );//check

        var innerHTMLOfActiveTabAnchor = $(".mdl-tabs__tab, .is-active").html();

        $("#chooseColumnsForm").html(  "<input type='hidden' name='activeTabTitle' value='"+innerHTMLOfActiveTabAnchor+"' />" + $("#chooseColumnsForm").html()  );

        alert(  $("#chooseColumnsForm").html()  );//check

        $("#chooseColumnsForm").submit();

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that checked state is not stored in the html, it is a property of the *dom elements*.

The  **checked attribute** is not updated by user interaction and is only used by browser to set the **checked property** during initial rendering

This is the same for other attributes like `value` or `selected`

Use `append()` or `prepend()` to add only the hidden input instead of replacing the whole inner html of the form

Change

```
$("#chooseColumnsForm").html('<input.....>'  + $("#chooseColumnsForm").html())
```

to

```
$("#chooseColumnsForm").append('<input.....>')
```

This will leave all the other form elements as they were and not affect the checked property (or values for other types of controls)

Comment: Thank you very much. This has solved the problem of checkboxes, but the problem of the tabs remains. The tab selected when the page is first loaded is `Starks`. At the level of HTML, `Starks` tab has `is-active` class by default. But then I select the `Lannisters` tab, the `is-active` class is added to the `Lannisters` tab and is removed from the `Starks` tab. _THEN_ I click the `Save` button. - to be continued...

Comment: -continued from previous comment: But this change is not reflected in JS. In JS, inside the click listener of `Save` button, I check which tab has `is-active` class and assign the title of that tab to the `value` attribute of the Hidden `input` field. But it is always `Starks`, even when I have selected the `Lannisters` or `Targaryens` before clicking the `Save` button. That is the problem with tabs :s

Comment: selector is wrong.....you are looking for **either** `.mdl-tabs__tab` **or** `.is-active` and `html()` will only return first eleemnt in that collection

Comment: remove the comma in the selector

Comment: Thank you so very much indeed. Had to remove the comma as well as the space from the selector. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes#answer-1041352) also helped.

Comment: oops my bad about the space also

Answer (score -1):

for accessing the checked checkbox values, use an array for the 'name' attribute.
like this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="columnHeadersToDisplay[]" value="STRING-LABEL-OF-THIS-CHECKBOX" />
```