# jquery selector selector for class not working(bootpeg)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using [jquery bootpag](https://github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag) to display pagination on a page

`<div class="textgray showing"></div>`

How should I tell jQuery to select this div? I tried the following without but neither of these attempts work

`$(".textgray .showing").html("some text");`

`$(".textgray showing").html("some text");`

P.S I am a beginner in frontend so bear with me

Comment: `$(".textgray.showing")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space means the second part is inside the first one (it's called the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)). Remove it:

```
$(".textgray.showing").html("some text");
```

Comment: this should not be closed as typo?

Comment: Typo ? No, really not. It's probably a duplicate though. Find it and I'll close the question.

Comment: When I said typo I mean the "typo off topic" "cannot be reproduced once you have fixed the space" kind of close

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put that extra space in between selector. space in selector looks for descendant elements:

```
$(".textgray.showing").html("some text");
```