# click element 2 times with clone().appendTo()

Tags: javascript, class, click, append, clone

i need help
    i can't click the same element  with 2 different classes

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".hello,.ciao").on("click",function (){
        $(nera).clone().removeClass("hello").addClass("ciao").appendTo($('#dama tr 
         #'+sinistra));
        $(nera).remove();
```

'

Comment: Assuming that you're trying to detect the click on an element that has two classes, you may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with this line

```
$(".hello,ciao").on("click", function() {
```

There is no selector before `ciao`

I presume it will be like this

```
$(".hello,.ciao").on("click", function() {
```

Comment: i put the selector but nothing happens,i click the  element with class "hello" and works to appendTo() , i need to click again to this element to do something more

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.hello.ciao').on("click",function (){
        $(nera).clone().removeClass("hello").addClass("ciao").appendTo($('#dama tr 
         #'+sinistra));
        $(nera).remove();
```