# JQuery Click Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, jsfiddle

I'm trying to get my code to click and show an alert, but the code doesn't seem to work. I've written the code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/MGames/9eu94Lau/1/

Here is my html:

```
<div class="add-cart-button-col col-right">
<a class="checkout-button nsg-button nsg-grad--heeb-orange" href="https://mycheckoutlinkgoeshere.com" data-query="https://linkcheckoutgoeshere.com">
                      CHECKOUT
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

And here is the code that does not to show the alert after clicking

```
$(".checkout-button nsg-button nsg-grad--heeb-orange").click(function() {
  alert('hohoho');
});
```

I would appreciate the help to find out what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Edit: This question is different due to the fact that I'm asking for clarification for an error that was present in my code. It's not a duplicate of selecting an element with multiple classes...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes-in-jquery

Comment: `.checkout-button nsg-button nsg-grad--heeb-orange` !== `.checkout-button .nsg-button .nsg-grad--heeb-orange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 forgot to add`.` before each class.

2.Remove spaces in between all classes (as you are trying all classes of single element not parent-child)

Working snippet:-

```js
$(".checkout-button.nsg-button.nsg-grad--heeb-orange").click(function() {
  alert('hohoho');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-cart-button-col col-right">
  <a class="checkout-button nsg-button nsg-grad--heeb-orange" href="https://mycheckoutlinkgoeshere.com" data query="https://linkcheckoutgoeshere.com">CHECKOUT</a>
</div>
```

Reference:-[How can I select an element with multiple classes in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041352/4248328)

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple classes in a jQuery selector is done with multiple periods, like so

```
$(".checkout-button.nsg-button.nsg-grad--heeb-orange")
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/9eu94Lau/2/)

With no spaces between the classNames, it matches an element that has all the classes

Answer (score 2):

The CSS selector is wrong here.
Correct selector:

```
 $(".checkout-button.nsg-button.nsg-grad--heeb-orange").click(function() {
    alert('hohoho');
   });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9eu94Lau/3/

Refer this for more details on CSS selectors: https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
$("a[class='checkout-button nsg-button nsg-grad--heeb-orange']").click(function() {
  alert('hohoho');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

```
$(".checkout-button.nsg-button.nsg-grad--heeb-orange").click(function() {
  alert('hohoho');
});
```

When we have multiple class, then we add **. operator** at the time of accessing the elements.