# Remove method using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some element I want to remove but I want to keep the one that have a certain attribute

Here is my code

```
    $(".glarry-" + activegallery + " " + ".product-gallery .thumbnails .thumbnail").not('[data-source="'+ $(this).data('source') +'"]').remove();
```

I also tried this

```
    $(".glarry-" + activegallery + " " + ".product-gallery .thumbnails .thumbnail:not([data-source='" + $(this).data('source') + "'])").remove();
```

This remove all the element, irrespective of the `not`

Answer (score 0):

It might be because there is a space between each class name in the jquery selector.

Take a look at this post.

[How can I select an element with multiple classes in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes-in-jquery)

For a selector that considers all those clases they must be put together

```
$('.a.b')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this kind of Selector

```
$(".example[attribute]").remove()
```

the selector above will get you all the atrribute with the class "example" with an attribute called "attribute" and the remove all of that selected element