# How to filter products by class name, then filter again by a second class name

Tags: javascript, filter, filtering, getelementsbyclassname

I have 100 products on my page that i need to filter by their location > display the results > then filter those results by the category they belong to > show those results only.

The primary filter is 9 location buttons, if they select location1 > only display products with class name "location1"

The secondary filter is 5 category buttons, if they select category1 > only display products from location1 AND category1.

The expectation is that the products shown are only the ones that meet both requirements of the primary filter (locations) and the secondary filter (categories). I have each product's location and category assigned in the div class.

2 examples:

Example 1) User clicks button [location1] and then clicks button [category2] and sees what's available that meets BOTH location1 and category2. User then clicks the button [location3] and sees what's available that meets both location3 and category2.

Example 2) User clicks button [location1] and then clicks button [category2] and sees what's available that meets BOTH location1 and category2. User then clicks the button [category4] and sees what's available that meets both location1 and category4.

<button class="btn  active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> SHOW ALL</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Los Angeles')">LOS ANGELES</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Bay Area')">BAY AREA </button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Fresno')"> FRESNO </button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('San Diego')">SAN DIEGO</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Sacramento')"> SACRAMENTO </button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Reno')"> RENO</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Las Vegas')">LAS VEGAS</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Portland')"> PORTLAND </button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection('Hawaii')"> HAWAII</button>

```
  <div id="my2BtnContainer" style="margin: 30px auto 100px;">


<button class="shows btn  active" onclick="filterSelection0('all')"> SHOW ALL</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection0('Air Side')"> AIR SIDE</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection0('Water Side')"> WATER SIDE</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection0('Refrigeration')"> REFRIGERATION</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection0('Air Motion & Control')"> AIR MOTION & CONTROL</button>
<button class="btn " onclick="filterSelection0('Plumbing')"> PLUMBING</button>



  </div>

<script>




filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    if (c == "all") c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }

}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
    }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
            arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}



// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

---

everything above works for the location filtering of the products, but i dont know what to do for the category filters ( air, water, refrigeration, motion control, plumbing)

Comment: I know how to do it with: `jQuery(".class1.class2")`. I think they use a filter rather than a `getElementByClassName()`.

Comment: How would I go about that? do you have any examples I can take a look at?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/how-can-i-select-an-element-with-multiple-classes-in-jquery — otherwise read up about [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) on their website.