# Add 'current-menu-item' class to div based on URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add the class `current-menu-item` to the following div:

`<div class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom jet-custom-nav__item jet-custom-nav__item-6068">`

Afterwards it should be

`<div class="**current-menu-item** menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom jet-custom-nav__item jet-custom-nav__item-6068">`

This is how my .js looks like so far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(window.location.href.match('harmonikapuls.com/konto/adressen/rechnungsadresse')){
        $("menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.jet-custom-nav__item.jet-custom-nav__item-6068").addClass("current-menu-item");
    }
});
```

Basically I just want not a specific URL but everything after the slug `/adressen/` this was just for trying. I call my function over my function.php

Comment: You're missing a leading dot on your selector.

Answer (score 0):

You must include dots when using the jQuery selector to find elements by class names.

Furthermore, since you're selecting a `div` that contains all of the named classes, they must not be separated by space, so `$(".menu-item.menu-item-type...")`. If you separated the class names by space, it would look for the children of the previous class name. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041344/11579013).

Also, it would be wiser to add a unique id to the `div` element by adding an attribute `id="myDiv"` and then use a hashtag in the selector: `$("#myDiv")` - it would be more efficient and clearer. If you don't want to use an id, you can select the element just by the class that uniquely identifies it, so for example `$(".jet-custom-nav__item-6068")`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still in the learning phase. I removed spaces and seperated with dots but somehow it's still not working.

Comment: Did you look whether the element is found? You can check that by `if ($('...').length > 0)`. Also, the `.jet-custom-nav__item-6068` seems to have a randomly generated value at the end. Does the element you want to select have the same number there each time you reload the page?

Comment: It works now! I called my function wrong in the functions.php as my  `$scr` was wrong. Now the only question left how can change the URL to a slug and everything after.