# Javascript - apply a class to iframe with two different type of sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors, src

How can I target more than element in a single jQuery selector?

I am trying do add a class to all my soundcloud and youtube widget when a page is loaded. I have no problem doing it for soundcloud, with this :

```
 $("iframe[src^='https://w.soundcloud.com/']").addClass("widget");
```

I would like to apply this class to a youtube iframe as well.  How can I select both iframes?  I tried with :

```
$("iframe[src^='https://w.soundcloud.com/' or src^='http://www.youtube.com']").addClass("widget");
```

That, as well as other of my attempts, do not work...

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Similar to [jQuery - Selecting Multiple Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488305/jquery-selecting-multiple-classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selectors use `,` for 'or' which is known as grouping in CSS.

```
$("iframe[src^='https://w.soundcloud.com/'], iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']").addClass("widget");
```

Source: [W3C "Grouping"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping)

Comment: @user2461866 Would you mind marking the post as accepted? [StackOverflow: About - look for "accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Selector syntax oesn't support `or`.  The way of alternating two selectors is `,`:

```
$("iframe[src^='https://w.soundcloud.com/'], iframe['src^='http://www.youtube.com']").addClass("widget");
```