# Multiple class selector to wrap div around

Tags: jquery

I have 2 elements that I want to wrap with a new div.

```
  <div class="bigfont-m capsletter"></div> 
  <div class="headfont6 text-overhide"></div>
```

Is it possible to select both at once and use the `.wrap()` JQuery method ?

I know about the multiple selector (,) but not working on my side.

What I want is the new div to be like that

```
  <div>
  <div class="bigfont-m capsletter"></div> 
  <div class="headfont6 text-overhide"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to select both the elements and then use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap them with an element

```
$('.bigfont-m.capsletter, .headfont6.text-overhide').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8uU6A/)

Comment: @upvoters: You are all simply showing partiality.. :D

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery - Selecting Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488305/jquery-selecting-multiple-classes)

[How can I select an element with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041344/jquery-multiple-class-selector)

```
$('bigfont-m.capsletter, headfont6.text-overhide') is your selector
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [**`wrapall()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) method

### <kbd>[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mfhY8/)</kbd>

```
$('div.bigfont-m.capsletter,div.headfont6.text-overhide').wrapAll('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can use `.add()`, As everyone already mentioned `multiple selector`, Then you can use `.wrapAll()`

```
$('.capsletter').add('.headfont6').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4VTGA/)