# Simple multiple selection with AND and not OR of classes, tags etc? JS

Tags: javascript

What should I use in order to select multiple tags, classes etc? By multiple I mean this:

```
.cssclassone { blablabla }
.cssclasstwo { blablabla }
.cssclassthree { blablabla }
```

How should I select all of them? Like `.cssclassone` AND `.cssclasstwo` AND `.cssclassthree`;

**NOTE** I need it with AND, not OR

**UPDATE**
better example of what I'm talking about:
HTML:

```
<div class="cssclassone"></div>
<div class="cssclassone"></div>
<div class="cssclassthree"></div>
```

I wanna target `cssclassone` AND `cssclasstwo` AND `cssclassthree` :) With JS :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Selecting Multiple Classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488305/jquery-selecting-multiple-classes)

Comment: It's not with AND, but with OR selection. and it's jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) will do it:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".cssclassone, .cssclasstwo, .cssclassthree");
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt3z01db/4/).

Comment: This not working bro... If I wanna make it work I should declare the [number] for each of them... Am I missing something?

Comment: @franenos What do you mean with _declare the `[number]`_?

Comment: Look here for example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_queryselectorall_multiple

Comment: @franenos Separating the elements with commas performs the OR operation, which is not what you intend to do. Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt3z01db/3/).

Comment: @franenos As you can see, the first two elements are selected (they have the three classes), but not the third one (it has only two of the classes).

Comment: some misunderstanding in place :) Updated the question bud, have a look

Comment: Ok, in that case you need commas. I'll update the answer.

Comment: So how come this not working for me?! wth... See here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/franenos/g51bt039/3/

Comment: Because `querySelectorAll()` returns an array and you must update the elements one by one. Look at this [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/g51bt039/4/).

Comment: Yeah... so, I can't use this without this [number] :) I want to simply select them by comma or something to target them all at once... No chance for this, huh? Like `document.querySelectorAll(".exampleone, .exampletwo").style.backgroundColor = "red"; `

Comment: I'm sorry for the `[number]` and so, I'm just learning all this :)

Comment: @franenos No, there's no way to perform that unless you use jQuery. You need to access each element individually.