# How to use single function to multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sample1').click(function(){
            $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible-dropdown');
        })
    })
</script>
```

It adds class so I can get some animations with mouse click event.
I have some more classes in HTML like 'sample2', 'sample3', etc. and would like to add exactly the same animations (classes of course has different content).

I know one solution, namely just add in same code n-times, but change class for each block of code. Is there a shorter way? I thought maybe something with arrays, not sure. I'm not really good in JS, it's like my first time ;)

Comment: See multiple selection with jQuery https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Simply one way, `$(".sample1, .sample2, .sample3").click(..`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Selecting Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488305/jquery-selecting-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just group the classes, separated by commas. Example :

```
$('.sample1, .sample2, .sample3').click(function(){
```

Comment: okay, that's the easiest way and it solves my question ;) but after added to my code it works for every class I wrote and I didn't expect that when I was writing question... E.g. now when element with class 'sample3' is clicked I'd like to make animation just to that one class. I think it doesn't work, because  the 'dropdown-content' class is added in each 'samples' classes (this is stupid hah). Is there still way to make it in one function? ;)

Comment: I need to see more of your code to answer accurately because I can't see the side effects you are describing. But my first intuition to answer your problem is using jQuery's `$(this)` selector. Like I said, I would need to see more of your code to tell you how to implement it.

Comment: I'd like to get similar effect like on this site: [link](http://kursjs.pl/kurs/wstep/wstep.php). When I click one of options on the sidebar navigation, it will show `<ul>` list with more options. Now, by using solution to my question, when I click one of options, it shows `<ul>` lists in each options, not just in one I clicked. This is what I got: [link](https://codepen.io/wolnio/pen/weEPLm)

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for this project? It seems simple enough to use vanilla JavaScript. Is there a reason for using jQuery?

Comment: Noo, there isn't. I'm just totaly new in JS and this code to add class (toggleClass) I found in google tutorials ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your code to take multiple selectors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sample1, .sample2, .sample3').click(function(){
            $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible-dropdown');
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('.sample1, .sample2 , .sample3').click(function(){
   $('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('visible-dropdown');
})
```

You could try

```
$('*[class*="sample"]')
```

This is the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161869/jquery-how-to-select-all-the-class-elements-start-with-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selectors:

***Catch the elements which have classes started with 'sample':***

```
$('[class^=sample]').on('click',function(){

    //Do something
});
```

***Catch the elements which have classes ended with 'sample':***

```
    $('[class$=sample]').on('click',function(){

    //Do something
    });
```

To find more information about **css selectors**:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp