# Cannot remove a value when 2 items are selected

Tags: jquery

a problem here. I'm trying to remove a textArea value on 2 different buttons click (to be clear, when the button X and NO are clicked)

The problem is that when I'm selecting like this:

```
    $('#reject_loan_modal-no', '#close-loan-rejection').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loan-rejection-modal').modal('hide');
    $('#clientservice-loan_approval_comment').val('');
});
```

It doesn't work at all. But when I'm seperating these two into a different `.on('click')` events, it works fine.

But I don't want to duplicate the code, so looking for a proper way to do it..

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple classes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488305/selecting-multiple-classes-with-jquery) - no need to close the quotes - `$('#reject_loan_modal-no, #close-loan-rejection')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selectors are supposed to be placed within the same string:

```
$('#reject_loan_modal-no, #close-loan-rejection').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loan-rejection-modal').modal('hide');
    $('#clientservice-loan_approval_comment').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a class to both of these buttons and use that class as a jQuery selector.